# Jpeg compression quality in android

Tags: android, camera, jpeg, android-camera-intent

I am launching the image capture intent to take a picture, adding a uri so the picture is tiny. My problem is I want to set the output jpeg-quality before I start the activity.

```
ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
vals.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "test title");
vals.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

Uri imageFileUri = context.getContentResolver()
    .insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, vals);

Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri); 

context.startActivityForResult(i, CameraImportActivity.CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

I suppose I could downsample after the picture is taken, but if I can request the activity do it for me I would like to do so.

As bonus questions, how do I change the album they get saved to in the gallery, and how do I prevent the camera activity from saving a copy in the default location (on my phone it is "photos")